# Uncompilable Java Code using getValues

Tags: java

This is a question from a test about Java. It asks a strange question that asks a user to find which line can compile.  But I find each line cannot compile

```
List <Double> doubles = new LinkedList<>();
List <Integer> integers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

List<String> doubleValues = getValues(doubles);
List<String> intValues = getvalues(integers);
```

Given that Double and Integer are subclasses of Number, which declaration of getValues() method in the sample code above will compile without errors or warnings?

```
//a
List<String> getValues(List<? extends Number> list)

//b
public List <String> getValues(getlist)

//c
public List<String> getValues(List <String> list)

//d
public List<String> getValues(List list)

//e 
public List<String> getNumbers(List<Value> list)
```

Comment: I think you can simply try it out and see the error message on compiler :p

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, none of them will compile as-is since you don't have any enclosing class or interface. Also, none of the methods have bodies, so they could only potentially compile inside an interface since that makes them abstract by default.
After that, it's a matter of examining the syntax. Two of them have potentially valid syntax, but only one can work stand-alone. You should be able to figure it out.

Comment: yeah, I fixed that.  Sorry.